# calculated field in tableau with categories

Tags: calc, tableau-api

I have dimension with 3 categories
and a measure of total sales count
I want the ratio between one item of the category and the total

for example - 
I have a measure of fruit (Apple, Orange, Strawberry)
I want the ratio of apple sales divided by total sales

Having trouble with the syntax

```
sum(([sales(fruit)='Apple']))/sum([sales])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional aggregation to do that. Basically you just embed an `if` statement inside of the aggregate function like so:

```
SUM(IF [fruit] = 'Apple' THEN [sales] END) / SUM([sales])
```

The numerator `SUM` ignores all non-Apples, while the denominator includes all fruits.

Comment: this way, you would have to create a dedicated calculated field for every single item, which doesn't seem like the smartest thing to do...

Comment: There are only 3 categories. This is entirely manageable and helps OP with the syntax, as per the question. You are welcome to provide "smarter" answers...

Comment: I can produce a table - line for each group and view it as a percentile computed using "table down", to get ratio for each. I actually thought that creating a calculated field is easier

Comment: Additionally, it is more "portable" as you aren't required to include the categories in your view, and you can do things like use it as a reference line, etc.

Comment: Yes, but not usable once you start using filters etc.

Answer (score 0):

**user3581800**, very similar solution, but slightly more powerful (and complex as well) is to use so-called Level of Detail (**LOD**) expressions.

The main benefit is that they will allow you to "overwrite" filters should you need to use them (try adding *exclude* filter for "Orange, for example). Let's create a newly calculated field *Total Sales*:

```
{ FIXED : SUM([Sales]) }
```

This will produce a total sum of sales no matter what, and then you could create a calculated field as Nicarus suggested in his answer, even though this one should be more flexible:

```
SUM( IIF([Fruit] = "Apple", [Sales], 0) )  /  SUM( [Total Sales] )
```

Read more about the power of [LOD Expressions on Tableau blog](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions).